# Webpage element seems to be invisible to Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to click/sendKeys to a button labelled `Browse` on a webpage, and no matter what I try, Selenium fails to find it.

Using Selenium's IDE, I can gather the following information:

```
id=uploadField
name=uploadField
css=#uploadField
dom:name = document.uploadForm.uploadField
xpath:attributes = //input[@id='uploadField']
xpath:idRelative = //div[@id='browseBtnContainer']/form/input[4]
dom:index = document.uploadForm.elements[3]
xpath:position = //input[4]
```

And I've tried all of the following By. sequences, all of which throw a `NoSuchElementException`. There is only one iframe and I tried to switch to iframe but it didn't work.

```
WebElement browse = driver.findElement(By.id("uploadField"));
WebElement browse1 = driver.findElement(By.name("uploadField"));
WebElement browse2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#uploadField"));
WebElement browse3 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("uploadField")); // just in case
WebElement browse4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("uploadField")); // attributes
WebElement browse5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='browseBtnContainer']/form/input[4]")); // idrelative
WebElement browse6 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[4]")); // position
```

The container portion of the code confuses me. I don't know how to access the elements in a container, and anything I find on google just tells me to use the xpath, of which I can't seem to find.

Am I using the By.xpath incorrectly? How can I generate a list of every single element on the webpage?
Here is the relevant HTML source code:

```
   <div id="ext-comp-1022" class=" x-panel x-border-panel" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1077px;">
      <div id="ext-gen27" class="x-panel-bwrap">
         <div id="ext-gen28" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader"     style="overflow: auto; width: 1075px; height: 502px;">
            <div id="ext-comp-1023" class=" x-panel x-panel-noborder">
               <div id="stepOnePanel"/>
               <div id="stepTwoPanel"/>
               <div id="stepThreePanel"/>
               <div id="stepOnePanel" class="step-container" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 30px;">
                 <div class="step-title" style="background-color:transparent;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top left;background-image:url(/assets/icons/medium/icon-1.png );padding:12px 0px 0px 50px;height:30px;font-weight:bold;">Start by selecting the ZIP file which contains your images (20MB max)</div>
                <div id="ext-gen71" style="padding-left:70px;overflow:auto;">
                      <div id="ext-comp-1024" class=" x-panel x-panel-noborder">
                         <div id="ext-gen74" class="x-panel-bwrap">
                            <div id="ext-gen75" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader x-panel-body-noborder">
                                <div style="padding-top:2px">
                                   <div id="browseBtnContainer" style="float:left;width:85px;margin-top:-2px">
                                     <table id="browseBtn" class="x-btn stepBtn x-btn-noicon x-btn-over" cellspacing="0" style="width: 79px;">
                                     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" target="hiddenUploadFrame" method="post" action="/uploader/upload?actingAsUserId=pleach&currentAccountId=bmwofreading&uploadAccountId=bmwofreading&ccmode=multiwindow" name="uploadForm">
                                         <input id="doNotResize" type="checkbox" style="display:none" value="true" name="doNotResize"/>
                                         <input id="pdfConvert" type="checkbox" style="display:none" value="true" name="pdfConvert"/>
                                         <input type="hidden" value="false" name="previewNeeded"/>
                                         <input id="uploadField" type="file" size="1" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -19px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer; height: 22px;" name="uploadField"/>
```

Comment: please provide HTML code

Comment: @murali seleniumtrainer I've added the relevant HTML code

Comment: can you add sample url to replicate this issue

Comment: Is there `<frame>` or `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: try -> driver.switchto().frame(0); before clicking on your element ... if not work then try driver.switchto().frame(1);

Comment: may you show the iframe code and are you sure that this code is not visible after a click event?

Comment: @Guy You have pointed me in the right direction and my problem is now solved. I needed to switch to the default frame, and then into the application iframe and the element became visible. If you'd like to submit some kind of answer I can give you credit!

Comment: @ToddLeach I added an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to the `frame` in order to interact with the elements in it

```
driver.switchTo.frame("id"); //using the frame id attribute
// or
driver.switchTo.frame("name"); //using the frame name attribute
// or
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(...);
driver.switchTo.frame(frame); //using the frame as WebElement
```

And to switch back

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following method.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='uploadField']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per provided HTML, we can try directly by using id or name. If you are looking for xpath only, then try below relative xpath

```
 //input[@id='uploadField']
```

If directly click does not works then try with Actions. First move to element then try to click. i hope this way helps and works good for me on most of cases

```
Actions move=new Actions(driver);
    move.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='uploadField']"))).click().build().perform();
```

finally you can try by using javascript executor

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("uploadField"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Thank You,
Murali