# Check box inside table not working in Selenium Webdriver for Java

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a check box inside a table and I am not able to check it using Seleinum Webdriver in Java.  I'm using version 2.52.0 of Selenium.  It doesn't matter which web browser I use, I always get an element not found error.  I know that my iFrame is correct because I can click on every other component on this same screen.

Here's a picture of the screen:

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMt1B.jpg)

And here's the HTML code:

```html
<div id="j_id_jsp_2033766868_1pc7:innerTbl::db" class="x13r" _afrcolcount="4" style="position: relative; width: 958px; overflow: hidden; height: 320px; z-index: 1;">
  <table class="x13s x14j" cellspacing="0" _startrow="0" _rowcount="3" _selstate="{}" _totalwidth="395" style="table-layout: fixed; position: relative; width: 958px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="p_AFHighlighted x13q" _afrrk="0">
        <td class="xir" nowrap="" align="left" style="width:25px;">
        <td class="xir" nowrap="" align="left" style="width:50px;">
          <span id="j_id_jsp_2033766868_1pc7:innerTbl:0:select" class="p_AFHoverTarget x20j x1v" _adftrc="j_id_jsp_2033766868_1pc7:innerTbl:0:select::icon-style">
          <span class="x2e">
          <span class="xk2">
            <input id="j_id_jsp_2033766868_1pc7:innerTbl:0:select::content" class="xtj" type="checkbox" value="t" name="j_id_jsp_2033766868_1pc7:innerTbl:0:select"/>
          </span>
          </span>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td class="xir" nowrap="" align="left" style="width:100px;">
        <td class="xir" nowrap="" align="left" style="width: 763px;">
      </tr>
      <tr class="x13q" _afrrk="1">
      <tr class="x13q" _afrrk="2">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have mapped my xPath as:

**//*[@id='j_id_jsp_2033766868_1pc7:innerTbl:0:select::content']**

and

**//*[@name='j_id_jsp_2033766868_1pc7:innerTbl:0:select']**

and

**//*[@id='j_id_jsp_2033766868_1pc7:innerTbl::db']/table/tbody/tr/td/td/span/span/span/input**

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: post your HTML code here in question while not as an image .. people will look into better then looking into image

Comment: Thanks Shubham, I've edited the post to show the HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you can take help from value attribute

```
//input[@value='t']
```

I just now posted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000382/webpage-element-seems-to-be-invisible-to-selenium) to click on element by actions and also by using Javascript execution if normal click does not works as expected.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Thank you Murali, it worked perfectly.  Still don't know why the ID or the NAME didn't work, but you gave me a solution that works!  I hadn't thought of mapping to the value, great idea!

Comment: Actually its good to avoid locators having numbers.. They may be dynamic in nature..goes on changing on executions..